# Help with a weird partial derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Let's say I have a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a 3-tensor $W \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d \times d}$

I define $f(x) = \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k x_i x_j x_k W_{i,j,k}$

How would I compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?

I would think it would be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = \sum_j \sum_k x_j x_k W_{i,j,k}$

But when I compute both the numerical and the above analytical gradient, they don't match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Einstein summation convention](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html) was created 
for this kind of calculation.
$$\eqalign{
f &= x_ix_jx_k \,W_{ijk} \\
\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p}
 &=  \left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_p}\right)x_jx_k W_{ijk} 
+ x_i\left(\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_p}\right)x_k W_{ijk} 
+ x_ix_j\left(\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_p}\right) W_{ijk} \\
 &=(\delta_{ip})x_jx_k W_{ijk} 
+ x_i(\delta_{jp})x_k W_{ijk} 
+ x_ix_j(\delta_{kp}) W_{ijk} \\
 &= x_jx_k W_{pjk} + x_ix_k W_{ipk} + x_ix_j W_{ijp} \\
 &= x_jx_k W_{pjk} + x_jx_k W_{jpk} + x_jx_k W_{jkp} \\
}$$
Or using explicit summations 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p}
 &= \sum_j\sum_k x_jx_k\big(W_{pjk}+W_{jpk}+W_{jkp}\big) \\
}$$

Comment: Sorry to barge in. Just out of curiosity and for my learning, greg. How is the last line of gradient computation equal to the previous line?

Comment: The idea of a repeated _dummy index_ is that its actual name doesn't matter. For example, the equality $x_ix_kW_{ipk}=x_jx_kW_{jpk}\,$ follows from substituting $(i\to j)$. The third term requires a double substitution $(i,j\to j,k)\;$

Comment: Thank you, greg!

Comment: Thank you! Happy to confirm that this accords with my numerically computed gradient.